# Can't install Texstudio 4.6.3 on my M2 MacBook Pro?

Tags: texstudio, installing, mac, mactex, macos

I recently transitioned from Windows to apple silicon. I have a MacBook M2 Pro. I am trying to download Texstudio 4.6.3 on my machine. However, when I double click on the downloaded Texstudio file, I get the dialogue box saying that "To open Texstudio you need to install Rosetta". I don't want to install Rosetta on my machine because I don't know what it is how it works. Can somebody help me with this? Is there a way to work with LaTeX on my machine without downloading the Rosetta?

Comment: Rosetta is a tool from apple which allows to execute programs compiled for intel processors on macs with M chips.

Comment: I don't know about texstudio but that's just the editor, but mactex has native arm binaries for Mac https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html  rosetta is the apple emulator so arm machines can run programs compiled for intel Mac

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ; Would I get all the features on mactex which are available on Texstudio? I am pretty familiar with the Texstudio.

Comment: You'll need both. Mactex provides the tex distribution. TexStudio is an editor.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ; Which editor shall I install if I don't want to install rosetta?

Comment: I have no idea about texstudio (or macs) but you can use any editor you like. (I think mactex comes with one doesn't it, or personally I'd use emacs)

Comment: I'm a big fan of texstudio, so I would suggest to not give up on it. Personally, I would install rosetta, there are still many applications which are not available for M chips. If you really don't want it, I've seen comments from the texstudio developer which suggest to install it via homebrew https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1641#issuecomment-850999001 (I don't know if this is still the recommended way). It is also possible to compile texstudio yourself, the instructions can be found on github, although getting all the dependencies was a bit tricky.

Comment: There used to be Rosetta also during the transition from PowerPC to Intel processors. The tool is made by Apple and is completely safe. You *do* need it, because several apps aren't yet complied for M1 or M2 chips.

Comment: You can also maybe try to add support for darwin in the nix derivation ^^

Comment: You could use TeXShop instead of TeXStudio; it's automatically installed if you install MacTeX, and does not need Rosetta.  However, I would definitely install Rosetta.  A year ago, I made the transition from an Intel Mac to one with an Apple M2, and one of the first things I did was to install Rosetta (officially it's Rosetta 2), since a number of applications wouldn't run without it.  Here's Apple's support page https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861